# XAMPP phpMyAdmin - Access forbidden!

Tags: httpd.conf, phpmyadmin, xampp, windows-7

I can't access PHPMyAdmin. I have installed XAMPPlite 1.6.5 on Windows 7. I haven't changed any config, except `.htaccess`, where I added the third line:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from localhost
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error when I try to access phpMyAdmin or security from localhost.

> Access forbidden!
>
> You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either
>   read-protected or not readable by the server.

Comment: I wonder why I was downvoted

Answer (score 1):

First question: Are you actually accessing it from `localhost`? (127.0.0.1 ONLY!)

In your `httpd.conf` file or somewhere in the main Apache config, you've probably got a line like "`AllowOverride None`" and should be set to `All` instead. (That prevents `.htaccess` files from working properly (security).

Or even it might in the PHPMyAdmin configuration. I couldn't tell you where that is because I don't know what operating system you use (it varies).

Comment: Yes, I am accessing it from localhost (http://localhost/xampp/). I am using Windows

Comment: @Casebash - Windows... In your Apache config, there may be a file in the `includes` folder called "security.conf" or similar. Look for a block with PHPMyAdmin in a `VirtualHost` container and see if there's an `AllowOverride None`

Comment: I can't even find an includes folder :-(